# react-native-video. How to unmount video?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-video

I use react-native-video and react-native-video-player libraries. And my question is next - how to unmount video?
I have a list of videos (I make request to take all of them but show only 5 at first, than i press button "Show more" and load 5 more videos, but if I play more than 8 videos(play and paused) all the others videos stop working - I press play control of video and video becomes white). I there way to unmount previous videos by pressing "Show more" or there is another way to avoid such problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to this problem?

Comment: This library sucks so much, it's just a wasteland of dead ends and unresolved issues. Facebook should pay to have people maintain it.